# Angular ng-click is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
$scope.createField="<div class='form-group'><label class='col-lg-5'>"+fieldname+"</label><div class='col-lg-7'>"+fieldtypeitem+"</div></div>"+
    "<div class='col-lg-2 padding-le-re padding-re-re' data-ng-show='showbuttons'>" +
    "<a href='#' class='pl-edit-widget' data-ng-click='editFields()'><img src='images/edit_icon.png'></a>" +
    "<a href='#' class='pl-edit-remove'><img width='15' height='13' src='images/cross.png'></a></div>";
```

am creating a variable in this way but the ng-click is not working to me??

Comment: are you using a controller to modify the DOM?

Comment: That doesn't look like a very "angular" way of doing things, if it's in the controller.

Comment: Please show all relevant code. We have no idea what you are doing with that string

Comment: Yeah thats what I was thinking Lee. this should probably be a directive with access to its own scope

Comment: Do you use `$compile` to compile your string into `angular` code?

Comment: How are you appending this `html` from `$scope.createField` to DOM?

Answer (score 0):

This will never work at all, you are using angular very very wrong and need to read it's documentation and take a look at tutorials around.

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00

this shouldn't be the way to modify the template.

of course there are exceptions that need to be inserted to DOM from directive. for that you need to use $compile directive of angular but i am not going to tell you how to use that because in that case i will be guiding you to wrong path.

**learn from tutorials**

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want to create it dynamically its better for you to use angular directive instead of using this.As you are using scope variable to add element dynamically so you need the help of directive. I share a JSFiddle go through it.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('addElement', ['$compile',
    function($compile) {

      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, iElm, iAttr) {
          var id = 0;
          iElm.bind("click", function(e) {
            id++;

            var container = angular.element(document.querySelector("#container"));
            var addnewElem = $compile('<table border="1"><tr><td>id</td><td>' + id + '</td></tr><tr><td><button data-alert="hi">Click to Raead</button></td><td></td></tr></table>')(container);
            container.append(addnewElem);

            // Doubt
            // scope.dowork=function(){
            // alert('hi');
            //}
          });


        }
      };
    }
  ])
  .directive('alert', function() {
    // Runs during compile

    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind("click", function() {
        alert('hi');
      });
    };
  });
```

```html
<section ng-app="myApp">
  <button add-element>click me</button>
  <div id="container"></div>
</section>
```

Here is the fiddle
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/biswajitajatus/eg65quht/2/)